# How to use promises, or complete an ajax request before the function finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have the following function to check a users session to see if they're staff or not. Now, I know there are better ways to do this, but I'm trying to make a simple application that's tied with a forum software.

```
function isStaff(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url
    }).done(function(data) {
        var session = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (session.is_staff === 1) {
            callback(true);
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }

    });
}
```

Let's say I'm using this function in, like so, when compiling a "post" (Handlebars).

```
function compilePost(post) {
    var source = $('#feed-item-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {
        id: post.id,
        content: post.text,
        author: post.author,
        date: $.timeago(post.date),
        staff: function() {
            isStaff(function(response) {
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
    var html= template(context);
    return html;
}
```

Problem here, is that the request to check if a user is staff doesn't complete the request until after the function is ran.

I know with Promises is an alternative to async: false, where request is made and the response comes back before the function finishes.

But I have no idea how I can convert this into a promise. I've tried to learn it but I'm stuck at the concept. Can someone explain this to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, let's simplify the `compilePost` function. This function should know how to compile a post in a synchronous manner. Let's change the `isStaff` fetching to a simple argument.

```
function compilePost(post, isStaff) {
    var source = $('#feed-item-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {
        id: post.id,
        content: post.text,
        author: post.author,
        date: $.timeago(post.date),
        staff: isStaff
    }

    var html= template(context);
    return html;
}
```

Now, let's create a new method, with a single purpose - checking if a user is member of the staff:

```
function checkForStaffMemebership() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                var session = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (session.is_staff === 1) {
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This function wraps your original `ajax` call to the server with a promise, whenever the `$.ajax` call gets a response from the server, the promise will resolve with the answer whether the user is a staff member or not.

Now, we can write another function to orchestrate the process:

```
function compilePostAsync(post) {
    return checkForStaffMemebership()
        .then(function (isStaff) {
            return compilePost(post, isStaff);
        });
}
```

`compilePostAsync` finds out whether the user is a staff member or not. Then, it's compiling the post.

Please notice that `compilePostAsync` returns a promise, and thus if you used to have something like:

```
element.innerHTML = compilePost(post);
```

Now, you should change it to something like:

```
compilePostAsync(post).then(function (compiledPost) {
    element.innerHTML = compiledPost;
});
```

**Some notes:**

1. This is only an example, it surely misses some things (proper error handling for example)
2. The `isStaff` and `checkForStaffMemebership` (original and new) do not get any argument, I guess you'd figure out how to pass the userId or any other data you might need
3. Read about promises, it's a useful tool to have, there is a lot of data about it on the web, for example: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: "Now, we can write another function to orchestrate the process".... In what situation where I'd need a function to "orchestrate the process"? This is quite interesting to me.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you dont need to wrap the ajax with a promise which already implements promise. Instead chain the response as explained below.

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information)

**You can do something like below by chaining the response:**

```
function isStaff(url, post) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType:"json"
    }).then(function(resp){
        //resp = $.parseJSON(resp); /*You dont require this if you have respose as JSON object. Just Specify it in 'dataType'*/
        var source = $('#feed-item-template').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var context = {
            id: post.id,
            content: post.text,
            author: post.author,
            date: $.timeago(post.date),
            staff: resp.is_staff === 1 ? true : false
        };

        return template(context);
    });
}

isStaff(url, post).done(function(template){
    /*Your compiled template code is available here*/
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   console.log("Error:"+textStatus);
});
```

**Note:** Be sure to implement [error callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) also. Because you may never know what
went wrong :)

---

### Simple explanation about promise with $.defer:

For understanding i have created the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8zygkx7/1/) similar to your requirement.

**Explanation:**

Basically Promise is been introduced to attain synchronous execution of asynchronous JS code.

**What do you mean by Async or Asynchronous code?**

The code that is executed may return a value at any given point of time which is not immediate. Famous example to support this statement would be `jquery ajax`.

**Why is it required?**

Promise implementations helps a developer to implement a synchronous code block which depends on asynchronous code  block for response,. like in ajax call when i make a request to server asking for a data string, i need to wait till the server responds back to me with a response data string which my synchronous code uses it to manipulate it , do some logic and update the UI.

Follow this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jquery/deferred-objects.html) where the author has explained with detailed examples.

**PS:** Jquery `$.defer` implements or wraps `promise` in quite a different way. Both are used for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
let basedataset = {}
let ajaxbase = {};
//setting api Urls
apiinterface();

function apiinterface() {
    ajaxbase.createuser = '/api/createuser'
}
//setting up payload for post method
basedataset.email = profile.getEmail()
basedataset.username = profile.getGivenName()
//setting up url for api 
ajaxbase.url = ajaxbase.createuser
ajaxbase.payload = basedataset;

//reusable promise based approach 
basepostmethod(ajaxbase).then(function(data) {
    console.log('common data', data);
}).catch(function(reason) {
    console.log('reason for rejection', reason)
});
//modular ajax (Post/GET) snippets
function basepostmethod(ajaxbase) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxbase.url,
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ajaxbase.payload,
            success: function(data) {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                reject(xhr)
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using async await in js would be like this:

```
async function getMyAjaxCall() {
  const someVariableName = await ajaxCallFunction();
}

function getMyAjaxCall() {
    return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `someURL`,
    headers: {
      'Accept':'application/json',
  },
    success: function(response) {
// in case you need something else done.
    }
    });
}
```